# CRUD app based on requests in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to bulid a crud app based on "requests" where the user have to create a request in order to Create/Edit/Delete. I would describe a simple example like this

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dob = models.DateField()
    # etc.
```

Now I want to control the creation of the employee which will be easy to me by adding two fields called "Approved" and "Approved By".

The problem now with editing. I want to create a request with OLD and NEW values. when the admin approve then apply the new values to the instance, otherwise delete the new values from the system.

So Far the best solution to me is to use ContentType framework by Django. like this.

```
ACTIONS = (
            ('C', 'Create'),
            ('D', 'Delete'),
            ('U', 'Update')
        )

class Requester(models.Model):

    """
    This is the base of all the requests
    """
    initiated_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name=_('Initiated By'), related_name="initiated_by")
    reviewed_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name=_('Reviewd By'), blank=True, null=True, related_name="reviewed_by")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('contenttypes.ContentType')
    item_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTIONS)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Created At'), auto_now_add=True)
    reviewed_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Reviewed At'), auto_now=True)
```

This works fine with me for creation and deletion requests. However, the update requests have to temporary save the new values. Which I couldn't find a way to do it other than creating a new model (Ex. Employee) and put the new values in it. then replace the values from the new one to the old one. finally delete the new one. which will cause a problem in IDs Employee with ID = 5 the next might be 7 based on the "Temporary saved instances in the database"

I need a solution to not apply the Update without more replication of the data.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`django-reversion`](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) and other similar [applications](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/versioning/).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid reversion will save the old values for any roll-back needed by the admin. What I need is to not apply the change to real model until admin approval.